# how to differ the machine code of jalr and beq in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

In RiSC-V, since the *opcode* and *funct3* of the instructions **`jalr`** and **`beq`** are the same, I'm wondering whether the machine would confuse them or not.
Or is there range limits of their RS and immediate?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions have the following func3 and opcode:

```
func3#  opcode#  opcode name    opcode#(hex)
 000    1100011    BEQ            63
 000    1100111    JALR           67
```

So, they are different in the value of the opcode#.

---

As a side note, you can use tools to see the differences, for example, using [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/releases), which is an easy to use simulator where you can type in assembly code the following, and see machine code for it:

```
    .text
    jalr zero zero 0
label:  
    beq zero zero label
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Erik! Just now I confirm that it is the printing mistake that the opcode from instructions of SB-type, they print 1100011 as 1100111. And now I get that. Last, thanks for your recommendation of RARS.